# Flask SQLAlchemy: application crashed on postgres server reboot

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a standard setup of flask_sqlalchemy and an AWS RDS with postgresql.

I initialize the DB adapter the standard way:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy()

db.init_app(app)

class Example(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(256))
```

If I reboot the RDS server and a SELECT starts during reboot I get:

> psycopg2.OperationalError: terminating connection due to administrator
>   command SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError)
>   terminating connection due to administrator command SSL connection has
>   been closed unexpectedly

That I understand. The DB is unavailable.

BUT: After that the application cannot recover from the situation because:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't reconnect until invalid
>   transaction is rolled back
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError:
>
> (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid
>   transaction is rolled back

I understand the application throws exceptions during reboot.

**But what puzzles me that it never recovers.**

There is no write transaction to the DB! I don't understand what rollback the exception is describing.

### Edit:

This is how all commits are implemented:

```
try: 
  db.session.commit() 
except Exception as e:                    
  db.session.rollback()
```

But there is no commit triggering the exception. Only SELECTS.

Comment: have you tried implementing anything "creative" to clean up the application and get it working? I understand this isn't your question, but from a practical standpoint, it's what I would do. Maybe the nuclear option, just re-initialize the database object as if the app was just starting up?

Comment: No I did not. But I have a reason: In the SQLAlchemy docs a reconnect functionality is described. But its not working for me.

Comment: I would suggest changing that `except` block. When catching `Exception` (ie. everything) it is almost always best to re-raise by adding `raise` as the last statement in the block. Without that, you are essentially saying "I have accounted for every possible exception that could ever occur in both my own code and all supporting libraries. There is zero probability of any unexpected behavior that cannot be fully recovered by this `rollback` method"

Answer (score 0):

Do this and it should fix it for you `session.rollback()`.

If you want to find this error, wrap it into a try/except-block and perform a session.rollback().

## EDIT:

So I test some of the stuff and I believe the reason for the error lies within the try/except block. Ideally the doc says this is how you should be implementing inserts:

1. Create the Python object
2. Add it to the session
3. Commit the session

e.g.

```
>>> db.session.add(User(name="Flask", email="example@example.com"))
>>> db.session.commit()
```

Likewise for deletes:

```
>>> db.session.delete(me)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

For querying you do not need to commit exclusively, the query attribute in Flask-SQLAlchemy does it for you on the Model class.

so for selecting you just do:

```
users = User.query.all()
```

Which in your case is:

```
 something = Example.query.all()
```

One more thing, can you please clarify or give more info on why you are implementing commits like this:

```
try: 
  db.session.commit() 
except Exception as e:                    
  db.session.rollback()
```

PS: I might have misread your last edit, my bad!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I added how all commits are implemented. But this error happens on SELECTS. No write. What rollback are we talking about here?

Comment: the problem isn't that they need to be closed, but that the session needs to rollback or commit when the session is returned. 
Every request you send creates a session and when your session gets a transaction request which is not committed or rolled back during the reboot, it throws that error(2nd error) you mentioned.

Comment: So the consequence you propose is to wrap each SELECT (e.g. Model.query.filter().all()) statement into a try/except block and do a rollback in case of an exception ?

Comment: check this out, it will clarity it for ya :)

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html

Comment: I understand the concept, but in flask_sqlalchemy there is no commit in querying. https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/#querying-records

Comment: Can you write an example code lines? Much appreciated

Comment: check the section for "Joining a Session into an External Transaction" @ the below menitoned:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html

Comment: sry but I dont understand your answer at all. You refer to "it" and I have no clue what you are referring to.

Comment: sorry about the confusion, I have added my commit, pls see if that helps.

Comment: Hope the above fixed it for you!